# Asp .Net Mvc Delete Doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone I'm trying to add edit and delete but delete doesnt work here is my index code for listing;

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Haberler)
                            {
                                <tr id="@item.Id" data-trid="tr_@item.Id">
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="sortable">
                                            <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs purple dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true">
                                                İşlem <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { Id = item.Id })" data-title="Kayıt Güncelle"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Düzenle</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="bsdelete" data-title="@item.Title" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete")" data-id="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Sil</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><a href="@item.Resim" data-rel="fancybox-button" class="fancybox-button">@item.Title</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

Here is my controller Delete;

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? Id)
    {
        if (!Id.HasValue)
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });

        try
        {
            var item = Db.Haberler.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id.Value);
            UrunSil(item);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });
        }

        return Json(new { IsComplete = true });
    }
```

And I send to AdminBaseController to delete ;

```
   public void DosyaSil(string yol)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~" + yol));
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public void UrunSil(News item)
    {

        DosyaSil(item.ResimBuyuk);
        DosyaSil(item.ResimKucuk);
        Db.Haberler.Remove(item);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Break points doesnt work when I click on delete icon it does nothing just like empty 
what could be the problem ?

When I click the delete button I get this error on console;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootbox is not definedglobal.js:113 (anonymous function)jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5 x.event.dispatchjquery-1.10.2.min.js:5 v.handle
```

Comment: do this after you remove the item Db.Entry(item).State=EntityState.Deleted;

Comment: Still Same I think something wrong with finding the delete in controller

Comment: Your 'delete' option is actually an anchor tag, but href is not actually pointing to anywhere. is it not required to have the url?

Comment: @Thangadurai is right, Your anchor link is not pointing any method!    If you could see in console it should be like- `<a href="/Delete"></a>`

Comment: @Thangadurai I think I'm sending it with URl.Action("Delete") but it doesnt work as I see

Comment: @Thangadurai But if I write href="/delete" it will be looking for a view it will be like localhost/Admin/News/delete and I think it will give another error ?

Comment: check preference of your js files. Order should be First Jquey file and the other js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete isn't work beacause The delete method isn't work beacause you is calling the wrong way, if you wanna call a delete action like this you need to redirect to another action process and return to "the Current View/Action". You can do this really simple with Ajax and Jquery, this is a sample:

```
    <li><a class="delete" data-toggle="bsdelete" data-title="@item.Title" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete")" data-id="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Sil</a></li>
```

And the js you need to do this:

```
 $(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function () {
       $.ajax({
           type: "DELETE",
           url: $(this).attr("data-url") + "?Id=" + $(this).attr("data-id"),
           success: function (data) {
             //Remake the search
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, exception, a, b){
                 alert(jqXHR.responseText);
           }
      });
   });
});
```

The Delete method don't recive the body of message and the Http verb use is Delete because the name of your action. So the parameter need to be in queryString on the Url.

Comment: Still no alert just Uncaught ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined in console.I dont even get error function I dont know why

Comment: try put this in the header of your page: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.3.0/bootbox.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Yes I've seen that my bootbos.min.js was curropted and this fixed my issue thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Add class name for **`<a>`** as below:

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="delete" data-toggle="bsdelete" data-title="@item.Title" data-    url="@Url.Action("Delete")" data-id="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Sil</a></li>
```

Use ajax to call the controller as below  :

```
$(function(){
   $(".delete").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
        data: "Id="+$(this).attr("data-id"),
       success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
       }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: I've also tried that and Also now I only made an alert when its called but still nothing doesnt even alert

Comment: check your firebug if any javascript errors are there?

Comment: check preference of you js files. Order should be First Jquey file and the other js files.